# How to change the format of FrameTicks

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here is a plot with the default frame ticks

```
S1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Now, if I define myself the range as well as the step separation of the left frame ticks by

```
S2 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, 
  Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Range[-1, 1, 0.2], Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
  Axes -> False]
```

I get the following output

[image]

Well, there are two obvious issues. First of all, 0 should be not be shown in CPU accuracy. Moreover, all ticks should have the same number of decimal digits so, -1. should be -1.0, 1. should be 1.0 and 0 should be 0.0.

How can I get this?

Comment: Try this first and then redo the plot. `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintPrecision -> 6]` screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/68TIV.png)

Comment: @Nasser I used this option but it had no effect.

Comment: No problem with '0' for me. You can try to use `ClearAll["Global`*"]` to remove the definition of S1, S2 before plotting and try to add `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision` in the Plot command.

Comment: No problem with 0 for me either... in any case, you can just `Chop` the ticks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -7, 7}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {{{#, NumberForm[N@#, {2, 1}]} & /@ Range[-1, 1, 0.2], Automatic},
 {Automatic, Automatic}}, Axes -> False]
```